# Building a selectbox with a different style for include_blank in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have a select box with a blank option:

```
<%= form.select :field_id, @options, {:include_blank => "No value"} %>
```

This will generate the following html for the select field:

```
<select name="model[field_id]" id="model_field_id">
  <option value="">No value</option>
  <option value="1">some value</option>
  <option value="2">another value</option>
</select>
```

I want this blank option to be styled differently (e.g. italic), preferably using a class:

```
<select name="model[field_id]" id="model_field_id">
  <option value="" class="empty">No value</option>
  <option value="1">some value</option>
  <option value="2">another value</option>
</select>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS attribute selectors:

```
option[value=""] { background-color: red; }
```

[Check out this Fiddle to see it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/bclennox/ZbpUV/)

Be aware that certain browsers (like Safari) don't allow much if any styling of options in a select, so don't depend on this too heavily.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This solution doesn't use a class. If I want to change the value of the option in the future, I have to change the css, too. How can I trick rails into generating a class attribute for the blank option?

Comment: You would have to monkey patch Rails, which is certainly less maintainable than changing your own CSS. You also don't have any control over the value of the blank option inserted by Rails, so I wouldn't expect that value to change very often, if ever.

Comment: Anyone know if this has changed in newer versions of Rails?  The question and comment here are now pretty old.